# Poles of Rankin-Selberg $L(s,\pi\times\tilde \pi)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, langlands-conjectures

Let $F$ be a number field and let $\pi$ be a cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{A_F})$.

Do we know that $L(s,\pi\times \tilde\pi)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$?

Do we know that $\frac{L(s,\pi\times \tilde\pi)}{\zeta_F(s)}$ is holomorphic at $s=1$?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that $\pi$ is cuspidal, then $L(s,\pi \times \tilde{\pi})$ *always* has a simple pole at $s = 1$. You can probably find this many places, but one such is [this paper](http://math.osu.edu/~cogdell/rorsc-www.ps) of Cogdell and Piatetski-Shapiro (see the Corollary on page 21, at the very end).

The answer to the second question is also yes, because the Dirichlet class number formula implies that $\zeta_{F}(s)$ also has a simple pole at $s = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning.** I was thinking on $\pi$ not neccesarily cuspidal. Jeremy Rouse's answer is the correct one.

$L(s,\pi_1\times \pi_2)$ has a pole at $s=1$ if $\pi_2=\tilde\pi_1$, but it is not neccesarily simple.

I'm sure that $L(s,\pi\times \tilde\pi)/\zeta_F(s)$ is holomorphic for some $\pi$, but I suspect that the problem should be open in general. Note that we don't know if $\zeta_F(s)/\zeta(s)$ is an entire function for non-Galois $F$.